# How to make a function that is wrapped inside a function returns on behalf of the parent function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that inside a function. I want the parent function to return an updated object (after the loop ends), currently, it returns undefined because the parent function returns nothing, only the child function `function(items)` returns data. How can I make the parent function returns updated `return_data`? Thanks a lot.

```
reportParser: (report) => {
    const return_data = {
        "click": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_75_'].style_12",
        "clicker": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_74_'].style_12",
        "openning": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "openner": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "name": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_7_'].style_12",
        "subject": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_9_'].style_12",
        "audience": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_11_'].style_12",
        "sent_mails": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_20_'].style_12",
        "send_date": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_32_'].style_12",
        "cancel_subscription_click": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "cancel_subscription_clicker": ".style_25 > .style_24"
    };
    let remaining_keys = Object.keys(return_data).length;
    for (let key in return_data) {
        if (return_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            html2json.parse(report, function () {
                return this.map(return_data[key], function ($item) {
                    return $item.text();
                });
            }).done(function (items) {
                if (key === "click" || key === "clicker" || key === "sent_mails") {
                    items[0] = items[0].replace(/,/g, "");
                    return_data[key] = parseInt(items[0]);
                } else if (key === "openning") {
                    items[items.length - 2] = items[items.length - 2].replace(/,/g, "");
                    return_data[key] = parseInt(items[items.length - 2]);
                } else if (key === "openner") {
                    items[items.length - 3] = items[items.length - 3].replace(/,/g, "");
                    return_data[key] = parseInt(items[items.length - 3]);
                } else if (key === "cancel_subscription_click") {
                    return_data[key] = parseInt(items[13]) + parseInt(items[18]) + parseInt(items[23]);
                } else if (key === "cancel_subscription_clicker") {
                    return_data[key] = parseInt(items[11]) + parseInt(items[16]) + parseInt(items[21]);
                } else {
                    return_data[key] = items[0];
                }
                remaining_keys--;
                if (remaining_keys === 0) {
                    return_data["click"] -= return_data["cancel_subscription_click"];
                    return_data["clicker"] -= return_data["cancel_subscription_clicker"];
                    delete return_data.cancel_subscription_click;
                    delete return_data.cancel_subscription_clicker;
                    logger.debug(return_data);
                    return return_data;
                }
            }, function (err) {
                // Handle error
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The execution would be function -> object init -> wait for loop to update object -> return object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a callback function or write this function as a promise.
Callback is a function you will pass into your function to execute after the data is done.

For the callback function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

```
reportParser = (report, callback) => { 
   //... process data
   html2json.parse(report, function() {
      //...
   }).done(function(items) {
      //after you have done process and get return_data, use callback
      callback(return_data);
   })
}
```

So when you using reportParser:

```
reportParser(report, function(return_data) { 
     //whatever you want to do with return_data
})
```

For the promise:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
reportParser = (report) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //... process data
        html2json.parse(report, function() {
        //...
        }).done(function(items) {
            //after you have done process and get return_data, use callback
             resolve(return_data);
        })
    })
}
```

And when you using reportParser function:

```
reportParse(report).then(return_data => { 
    //whatever you want to do with return_data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems `html2json.parse` return a Promise, so in your case you have to return a Promise as well in your parent function

```js
reportParser: (report) => {
    const return_data = {
        "click": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_75_'].style_12",
        "clicker": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_74_'].style_12",
        "openning": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "openner": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "name": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_7_'].style_12",
        "subject": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_9_'].style_12",
        "audience": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_11_'].style_12",
        "sent_mails": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_20_'].style_12",
        "send_date": "[id^='AUTOGENBOOKMARK_32_'].style_12",
        "cancel_subscription_click": ".style_25 > .style_24",
        "cancel_subscription_clicker": ".style_25 > .style_24"
    };
    let remaining_keys = Object.keys(return_data).length;

    /* here return a Promise */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let key in return_data) {
            if (return_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                html2json.parse(report, function () {
                    return this.map(return_data[key], function ($item) {
                        return $item.text();
                    });
                }).done(function (items) {
                    if (key === "click" || key === "clicker" || key === "sent_mails") {
                        items[0] = items[0].replace(/,/g, "");
                        return_data[key] = parseInt(items[0]);
                    } else if (key === "openning") {
                        items[items.length - 2] = items[items.length - 2].replace(/,/g, "");
                        return_data[key] = parseInt(items[items.length - 2]);
                    } else if (key === "openner") {
                        items[items.length - 3] = items[items.length - 3].replace(/,/g, "");
                        return_data[key] = parseInt(items[items.length - 3]);
                    } else if (key === "cancel_subscription_click") {
                        return_data[key] = parseInt(items[13]) + parseInt(items[18]) + parseInt(items[23]);
                    } else if (key === "cancel_subscription_clicker") {
                        return_data[key] = parseInt(items[11]) + parseInt(items[16]) + parseInt(items[21]);
                    } else {
                        return_data[key] = items[0];
                    }
                    remaining_keys--;
                    if (remaining_keys === 0) {
                        return_data["click"] -= return_data["cancel_subscription_click"];
                        return_data["clicker"] -= return_data["cancel_subscription_clicker"];
                        delete return_data.cancel_subscription_click;
                        delete return_data.cancel_subscription_clicker;
                        logger.debug(return_data);

                        /* RESOLVE THE PROMISE */
                        resolve(return_data);

                        return return_data;
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    // Handle error
                    
                    /* REJECT THE PROMISE ON ERROR */
                    reject(err);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

than you will able to use your function as a regular `Promise`

```js
reportParser(report).then((data) => {
    // Work with the returned data
}).catch((err) => {
    // Handle errors
})
```